# Why os.path.isdir() or os.path.existis() always return False

Tags: python, path, directory

I am using a function to test if a directory entered by user is valid or not. The user input doesn't go to the file name, it only goes to the folder name e.g. `"C:/Users/username/Desktop/folder"`. So I wrote the following function to get the path/directory:

```
def get_path():
     while True:
         file_path = input("Please enter file path (up to folder level); q to quit:> ")
         print(repr(file_path))
         if os.path.isdir(file_path):
             return file_path
         elif file_path.lower() == 'q':
             sys.exit()
         else:
             print("The path you entered is invalid.")
             continue
```

However, it always shows `The path you entered is invalid.` even though the path/string I entered is valid when running the os.path.isdir() in cmd.

Running the function on my Win10 cmd generates the following results

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> import pathlib
>>> def get_path():
...      while True:
...          file_path = input("Please enter file path (up to folder level); q to quit:> ")
...          print(repr(file_path))
...          if os.path.isdir(file_path):
...              return file_path
...          elif file_path.lower() == 'q':
...              sys.exit()
...          else:
...              print("The path you entered is invalid.")
...              continue
...
>>> path = get_path()
Please enter file path (up to folder level); q to quit:> "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/"
'"C:/Users/myname/Desktop/"'
The path you entered is invalid.
Please enter file path (up to folder level); q to quit:> "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/randomprojects"
'"C:/Users/myname/Desktop/randomprojects"'
The path you entered is invalid.
Please enter file path (up to folder level); q to quit:>
```

Comment: Please share the complete log where you get the error.

Comment: Well, it just never gets out of the condition `if os.path.isdir(path)`, the function itself has no issue, but any path input seems always return False

Comment: Can you share the path that you are entering? The code seems to be working fine on my side. `isdir` will not be able to find the file, it returns true only if the named directory is found. To have either of the file or folder name to be found, you should try `os.path.exists` only.

Comment: Sure, I entered: "C:/Users/username/Desktop/projectfold", no idea why it doesn't run from my side...it keeps returning the statement `The path you entered is invalid`

Comment: You don't have to enter the path in `" "` , just type plain `C:/Users/myname/Desktop/randomprojects` as the input, the rest will be handled automatically.

Comment: Huh...thanks a lot..I thought it requires `""` to enter it. Shame on me. Have a nice weekend! I really appreciate it.

Comment: haha, glad to help. Cheers!